# Pass two entities in one Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I have a little question:
When I want to build Forms with the `createForm()` function.
How I can add a second entity to this?

Here is my example code.

```
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Event();
    $picture = new Picture();

    $form   = $this->createForm(new EventType(), $entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
});
```

I tried the add function on `$form`, but it doesn't work.
Now I will add the Entity Fields from Picture to the form I created before.
Thank for your help.

Comment: Are the entities `event` and `picture` related ?

Comment: Yes OneToMany.
One Event has many pictures.

Comment: The have a look at the [how to embed a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) doc (its a fair chunk of work to get it working nicely)

Comment: Yeah its nice. But the input Type for Picture is empty. Maybe the Docu is for input and not for file upload?

Comment: It works just the same with file uploads - your `eventtype` has a collection of `picturetype`s - the picture type can contain a file

Comment: http://pastebin.com/J9v3h46i
This is my working Copy of the two Files, can u tell me please what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle your situtation whould be using subforms / field-types.

Create a form `EventPictureType` and add `EventType` and `PictureType` to it.

See the cookbook chapter [Embedded Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms) & [How to Create a Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html).